# Finding year that MMA functions were introduced via programmatic calls in the Wolfram Language

Tags: documentation, built-in-symbols, history

Is there a way to find the year that MMA functions were introduced via programmatic calls in the Wolfram Language? I would like to be able to create and manipulate such a list or dataset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What functions work in which version of Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175038/what-functions-work-in-which-version-of-mathematica)

Comment: These references are useful as they reference WolframLanguageData as does the answer below. Thanks for pointing me to them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> find the year that MMA functions were introduced via programmatic
> calls

You can use, as an example

```
 WolframLanguageData["DSolve", "DateIntroduced"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it is a matter of just running the above over all the commands you want.

The above returns a `DateObject`

See [Looping through all functions defined in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221555/looping-through-all-functions-defined-in-mathematica)  for example of looping over all build-in functions.

Comment: +1 We can also write things like `WolframLanguageData[All, {"Name", "DateIntroduced"}]`.

Comment: Did not know about the `WolframLanguageData` function. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Whoa, that's such a cool function! Thanks for sharing!